# call function when zoom in or out in Google map in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, zooming

i need to do something when user zoom in or out in google map in flutter, i have made it without problem, in this code inside GoogleMap class:

```
onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
            if (!model.userChangeMapType && model.mapType == MapType.normal && position.zoom >= 18.0)
              model.changeMapType();
            else if (!model.userChangeMapType && model.mapType == MapType.satellite && position.zoom < 18.0)
              model.changeMapType();
          },
```

but using this way mean my function will call even if user just moving the map, i need to implement it just when user zoom in or out in map